# Light fixture need help

Tags: light-fixture

I have a junction box in my bathroom that has two white wires coming from it two black wires two ground wires my light fixture has one black one white and a ground I hook the 2 black into the one come from the fixture same with the other wires. It light won’t work no clue what o did wrong can anyone help

Comment: Were the two white wire from the junction box originally connected together? Where the two black wires from the junction box originally  connected together?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both the light and the switch junction boxes please?

Answer (score 1):

Is the junction box at the ceiling? If so you may have a feeder and a cable going down and back to the switch. This would be called a switch leg and normally the hot feeder goes to the white going to the switch, the black wire coming back from the switch goes to the black on the light fixture.  The white from the same cable as the hot feeder goes to the white of the fixture,

If you have no test equipment and the breaker is off connect  the fixture white to one of the cables white and that same cables black to the fixture black and turn the breaker on, if the light turns on that is the feeder or supply, if It dosent it is the 2 wires going to the switch.

Connect them as instructed above with the breaker off and when you turn it on it will work with the switch.